# dojo issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, parsing, firefox, dojo

im using dojo 1.8 to create a website and it works fine using IE8. however, when i turn to firefox(version 20.0) and it cannot display the page properly. i feel like the parser didnt load when using ff, but i already set the parseOnLoad to true, and async to true as well. under that circumstance, the parser is supposed to load. anyone can help me out here? thanks!

type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true, async:true"

Comment: You will need to provide more detail.  This question is very general and difficult to answer.  Are there any errors in firebug?

Comment: in fact, i checked the firebug and i couldn't find the parseOnLoad property while the afteronload had been set true. i dont know how this happened. also, i got errors in firebug. here is the details:  Error: scriptError
_f()dojo.js (line 40)
req.injectUrl/_10a<()dojo.js (line 986)
 

return _c(new Error(_10),{src:"dojoLoader",info:_11});

dojo.js (line 40)

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, use http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js  This should give you a better error.

Comment: now i got this:   Error: scriptError
makeError()dojo.j...ssed.js (line 119)
req.injectUrl/errorDisconnector<()dojo.j...ssed.js (line 1669)
 

return mix(new Error(error), {src:"dojoLoader", info:info});

dojo.j...ssed.js (line 119)

src:

dojoLoader
dojo.j...ssed.js (line 1837)

info:

[

"http://ajax.googleapis....s/dojo/maqetta/space.js"

, error ]

dojo.j...ssed.js (line 1837)

Comment: stack:

makeError@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:119 req.injectUrl/errorDisconnector<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1669
dojo.j...ssed.js (line 1837)

fileName:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js
dojo.j...ssed.js (line 1837)

lineNumber:

119

dojo.j...ssed.js (line 1837)

columnNumber:

3

dojo.j...ssed.js (line 1837)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > now i got this: Error: scriptError makeError()dojo.j...ssed.js (line 119) req.injectUrl/errorDisconnector<()dojo.j...ssed.js (line 1669) return mix(new Error(error), {src:"dojoLoader", info:info}); dojo.j...ssed.js (line 119) src: dojoLoader dojo.j...ssed.js (line 1837) info: [ "ajax.googleapis....s/dojo/maqetta/space.js"

It looks like you haven't configured Dojo telling it where the maqetta module is.

See the paths property in http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/config.html#dojoconfig-parameters

Comment: cool. it fixed one of the errors and i still have one more. the display issue still exists, though.Error: scriptError
makeError()dojo.j...ssed.js (line 119)
req.injectUrl/errorDisconnector<()dojo.j...ssed.js (line 1669)
 

return mix(new Error(error), {src:"dojoLoader", info:info});

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace in your question?